# Issues while trying to execute git commands in server machine

Tags: git, pull, git-pull

I created a `git` environment locally.One system behaves like the `server` and I created another system as `gituser(client)`.My server repository is a bare repository.I used this `$ git clone --bare . ../../remote_repository.git` for creating this bare repository.Client made changes and `PUSH` updated file to  remote_repository.But the Server need to view and make update.Thats why I am trying to `PULL` the file.But I am receiving the below response.Other commands like `git status` etc are also giving the same response.Since I am a newbie I am very much confused.

**Received Response**

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I tried with the below  command.I am using `ubuntu`.

```
administrator@pramod-desktop:/$ git pull ../../remote_repository.git
```

**Command Explanation**

My bare repository path in server is `/home/user153/remote_repository.git`

```
../../remote_repository.git:`Path` to my remote_repository.git(git folder)
```

Anyone please help.

Comment: Is your "server" repository a *bare* repository? How did you *create* the repositories and why are you trying to `pull` from the "server" it would be more usual for "clients" to `push` to a centralised repository (where one exists).

Comment: Yeah..my server machine repository is a bare repository.I used this  $ git clone  --bare . ../../remote_repository.git for creating bare repository.Client made changes and push it to remote_repository.But the Server need to view and make update.Thats why I am trying to pull the file.Other commands like git status etc are also giving the same response.See my updated question.Since I am a newbie I am very much confused.Please help.

Comment: @ROOhhit: Questions are editable. Please, edit your comment into the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

administrator@pramod-desktop:/home/user153/workspace/repo02$ git pull ../../remote_repository.git

Here /home/user153/workspace/repo02 is the working folder where .git is resided in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Pull is an operation that needs **two arguments**, the repository to pull from and the repository to merge the pulled changes to. The target repository is found from current directory or from special option. When you write:

> ```
> administrator@pramod-desktop:/$ git pull ../../remote_repository.git
> ```

```
                              ^
```

Current working directory appears to be `/`. That definitely isn't a git repository. The synopsis of `git pull` is:

*target-repository*`$` `git` `pull` *name-of-source-repository*

or

*anywhere*`$` `git` `--git-dir=`*target-repository* `pull` *name-of-source-repository*

The *target-repository* must be a current working directory or must be given using the `--git-dir` option, but you are trying to pass it as argument.

The *name-of-source-repository* can be either URL or name of remote configured in `.git/config` (in bare repository that's just `config`).

If you want to check the file out on the server (indeed rather common operation), you should create another, non-bare clone. Than you need to call the `git pull` from that clone.

Comment: I am receiving the same error while running administrator@pramod-desktop:/$ git status.ie no git command is working .

Comment: @ROOhhit: Of course you are. Because _all_ git commands (well, most) need to be executed inside repository or work tree. And root directory is not one.

Comment: Jan Hudec:Here my bare repository path is (remote_repository.git-cloned from/home/user153/workspace/repo02) /home/user153/remote_repository.git.so I used this command to get status.administrator@pramod-desktop:/home/user153$ git status .this also showing the same error.Will you please point out where I went wrong.

Comment: @ROOhhit: The current working directory must be the directory that contains `.git` subdirectory. It still isn't. By the way, your comment is almost unintelligible; please take more care placing spaces on the correct side of punctuation marks and use backticks around literal strings.

Comment: Jan Hudec:I used this command : administrator@pramod-desktop:/home/user153 $ git pull ../../remote_repository.git.My .git folder is in /home/user153.